# File name problem when running snakemake with Tibanna

Tags: snakemake, tibanna

Given a simple rule to join two files,

```
rule run_A:
    input: 
        "A.txt", 
        "B.txt", 
        "C.txt"
    
    output: "Z.txt"
    
    resources:
        disk_mb=100
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

Local execution with

```
snakemake -j 1 Z.txt
```

runs with no problems.

Notice that input files are available at the s3 bucket,

```
(snakemake) pedro@Gen83-ubuntu:~/projects/sandbox/test$ aws s3 ls s3://grim-penguin/test/
2021-10-25 14:28:49          0 A.txt
2021-10-25 14:28:54          0 B.txt
2021-10-25 14:28:57          0 C.txt
```

Simply adding --tibanna, fails locally,

```
(snakemake) pedro@Gen83-ubuntu:~/projects/sandbox/test$ snakemake --tibanna -j 1 Z.txt
Error: --tibanna must be combined with --default-remote-prefix to provide bucket name and subdirectory (prefix) (e.g. 'bucketname/projectname')
```

Adding --default-remote-prefix also fails locally,

```
(snakemake) pedro@Gen83-ubuntu:~/projects/sandbox/test$ snakemake --tibanna --default-remote-prefix grim-penguin/test -j 1 Z.txt
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce Z.txt (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).
```

Prepending the remote prefix to the target now works locally,

```
(snakemake) pedro@Gen83-ubuntu:~/projects/sandbox/test$ snakemake --tibanna --default-remote-prefix grim-penguin/test -j 1 grim-penguin/test/Z.txt
```

but fails remotely with missing rule exception,

```
...
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce grim-penguin/test/Z.txt (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).
```

Local versions are,

```
(snakemake) pedro@Gen83-ubuntu:~/projects/sandbox/test$ snakemake --version
6.9.1
(snakemake) pedro@Gen83-ubuntu:~/projects/sandbox/test$ tibanna --version
tibanna 1.7.1
```

Paths without prefix fail locally and paths with prefix fail remotely. What am I missing here?